# Apply different colors for mark row

Tags: css

I want create css which should be mark row in different colors according to the condition of it

ex:

```
if row.Stage='new' (fill in green)
if row.Stage='complete' (fill in blue)

(row.stage is get the data from db)
```

please any one can help me to make this matter correct

Comment: How are you getting results from the database? PHP? How are you outputting the results? HTML? Including the relevant code you're working with would help. Or failing that at least fleshing out your Tags abit. There isn't enough to work off from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the classes you'll want, for example:

```
.new { background-color: green; }
.complete { background-color: blue; }
```

In the server side code, as you create the html for the rows, check the stage value - and add the appropriate CSS class to the row.

So a row with Stage as New will be as

```
<tr class="new"> ... </tr>
```